# Log all instances of a matched string in a array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I would like to find all instances of the matching string typed on the text box.

The current code is available as fiddle in-  https://jsfiddle.net/Mithun6319/Lzmekhph/

```
var colors = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Green', 'Grey'];

var boxHandeler = document.getElementById('box');

function textComplete(text) {
    boxHandeler.addEventListener('keyup', function (ev) {
       if (this.value.length >= 2) {
          var boxData = this.value;
          //console.log(boxData);
          for(i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
              while(colors[i].match(boxData)){
                  console.log[i];
              }
          }
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing in getting instances. Do you want to print count of the instances?

Comment: You have infinite while loop in case of match!

Comment: The fiddle has been updated. I would want it to work like an autocomplete text box.

Comment: You may have two match or more in your array. Suppose you enter "re" in your box then 'green' and 'grey' both will be selected. you can use <datalist> as other people suggested you, if you have not too much elements.

Comment: @hemantParihar he added validation for that if the `value.length >=2` only then it will match. By the way you do have good point

Comment: There will always be a chance of getting  more matches. So be careful for it. Even you take value.length >= 10. It just reduce the chances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want is an auto complete text box as you mentioned in comments. You can use `datalist`

```html
<input list='colors' />

<datalist id="colors">
  <option value="Red">
  <option value="Blue">
  <option value="Black">
  <option value="Green">
  <option value="Grey">
</datalist>
```

Either you can select from drop down list or type you will see filtered results

Here is how you can do it `javascript`. This is modified version of your code

```
<input type="text" id="box" onkeyup="matchThis(this.value)"/>

<script>
var colors = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Green', 'Grey'];

var boxHandeler = document.getElementById('box');

function matchThis(value){
        if (value.length >= 2) {
            var boxData = value;
            //console.info("Search String "+boxData);           
            var pattern = new RegExp(boxData,'gi');
            for(i=0;i<colors.length;i++){               
                if(colors[i].match(pattern)){
                    console.warn(colors[i]);
                }               
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

There was lot of issue with your code. First you were calling infinite loop(as mentioned in comments by @ananth) when match was found. You were trying to access console.log as an array

```
console.log[i];
```

Instead of

```
console.log(i);
```

For Some reason fiddle is not working so try it in your actual environment

Comment: Thanks!! I had this approach in mind, but wanted to do it via JavaScript and without using jQuery or any plugins.